# How find path at the m x n table

Tags: haskell

i have table m x n and pairs of points. For example, we can have table 3 x 3 and pairs of points:

A = (1,3),(3,2)
B = (1,2),(3,1)

I must find all paths which will be connect points in pairs.This paths can't intersect each other. We can go in left, right, down and up. In preceding example, we have followig paths:

A = (1,3) -> (2,3) -> (3,3) -> (3,2)
B = (1,2) -> (2,2) -> (2,1) -> (3,1)

(if is more solve, i would like have all)

Have anyone any concept how can i do it in haskell?

---

> Perhaps you could explain in words your Prolog algorithm

Ok, furthermore i have my code, so:

I have four predicate to go on left, right, up and down.

```
go((I1,J1),(I2,J2),_,_) :-
    J1 is J2,
    I2>=2,
    I1 is I2 - 1.

go((I1,J1),(I2,J2),_,N) :-
    I1 is I2,
    J2=<N-1,
    J1 is J2 + 1.

go((I1,J1),(I2,J2),M,_) :-
    J1 is J2,
    I2=<M-1,
    I1 is I2 + 1.

go((I1,J1),(I2,J2),_,_) :-
    I1 is I2,
    J2>=2,
    J1 is J2 - 1.
```

For example `go((I,J),(3,3),5,5)` returns

```
(I,J) = (2,3)
(I,J) = (4,3)
(I,J) = (3,2)
(I,J) = (3,4)
```

Of course, arguments 5 is size of table - here we have table 5x5.

I must knew, when is end of path, so i wrote:

```
endOfPath((I1,J1),(I2,J2)) :-
    I1 == I2,
    J1 == J2.
```

Then I could make predicate which will generate paths from point (I1,J1) to (I2,J2). First we must check if it is end of path:

```
generatePath((I1,J1),(I2,J2),T,T,_,_,_,B,B) :-
    endOfPath((I1,J1),(I2,J2)),!.
```

If it isn't end of path we must generate paths recursively.

```
generatePath((I1,J1),(I2,J2), Acc,T,M,N,Input,Bufor,NewBufor) :-
    go((I3,J3),(I2,J2),M,N),
    \+ member((I3,J3),Bufor),
    \+ member((I3,J3),Acc),
    \+ member((I3,J3),Input),
    generatePath((I1,J1),(I3,J3),[(I3,J3)|Acc],T,M,N,Input,[(I3,J3)|Bufor],NewBufor).
```

Thus, first we find point which is directly next to (I2,J2), then we check several conditions (for example, if (I3,J3) belong to any other path - it's wrong point). And then we generate path from (I1,J1) to (I3,J3) recursively. We have problem, when (I3,J3) is end of path, because (I3,J3) belong to Input and condition + member((I3,J3),Input) is not fulfilled.

Hence, I wrote the last predicate:

```
generatePath((I1,J1),(I2,J2), Acc,T,M,N,Input,Bufor,NewBufor) :-
    go((I3,J3),(I2,J2),M,N),
    \+ member((I3,J3),Acc),
    I3 == I1, J3 == J1,
    generatePath((I1,J1),(I3,J3),[(I3,J3)|Acc],T,M,N,Input,[(I3,J3)|Bufor],NewBufor).
```

It was quite easy and gives good results but I don't know how can I make it in Haskell. Really, I have very big problem and please help me.

Comment: What have you tried? Were you able to solve in any other language and struggling with implementing that in haskell? It looks an algortihmic question and not relevant to haskell until you say where you are stuck and need help with haskell implementation.

Comment: I done this task in Prolog. But i don't know how can i find any path between two points. In prolog it was quite easy, but i haven't any idea how can i do this in Haskell. How find any path between two points?

Comment: I think you can tag prolog too and add the prolog code which you have tried.

Comment: Do you have to move towards the other point of not?  Could a B path start (1,2) -> (1,3) ?

Comment: @DiegoNolan - B path can't start (1,2) -> (1,3) because point (1,3) belong to path A (and this is start point of this path).

Comment: @Satvik - I can't add my Prolog code because i don't have them at this laptop. So, could you help me?

Comment: Do you know, how can I generate only one path? If i'll able to generate one path, I'm sure that I'll could generate path for each other pairs of point, but now, it is very difficult for me to generate only one path between two points. Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain in words your Prolog algorithm.

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code translates as

```hs
go m n (i,j) = 
   [ (i+1,j) | i<m ] ++
   [ (i-1,j) | i>1 ] ++
   [ (i,j+1) | j<n ] ++
   [ (i,j-1) | j>1 ] 

-- isEndOfPath p q = p == q

genPath p q acc m n input buf = head $        -- since you have a cut there
                                  g p q acc buf 
  where
    g p q acc buf | p==q = [(acc,buf)]   -- return acc, buf
    g p q acc buf = [s |
                       r <- go m n q, notElem r buf, notElem r acc, 
                       notElem r input,
                       s <- g p r (r:acc) (r:buf)] ++
                    [s |
                       r <- go m n q, notElem r acc, 
                       r==p,
                       s <- g p r (r:acc) (r:buf)]
```